Equivalent GLM's for common stabilising transformations
I'm familiar with applying a log-transform to a skewed outcome variable to improve model fit, but I've not thought further to link stabilising transforms to GLM's in general. Reading around it seems there really aren't any excuses anymore for using a stabilising transformation of the outcome - I get a general sense that there is a GLM for every use case of the former. The obvious issue with stabilising transformations (aside from log which isn't that difficult) is the interpretability of the results.
Wondering if people can give me of the common equivalences? e.g. Instead of a log-transform, one could use a GLM with a gamma link? e.g. If you have an outcome consisting of proportions (including 0,1) you could use an arcsin transform or better still, beta regression? (but beta regression is not technically a GLM?)
Would be keen to hear the community's thoughts.

"Reading around it seems there really aren't any excuses anymore for using a stabilising transformation of the outcome - I get a general sense that there is a GLM for every use case of the former" One great "excuse" in my view is that more people are trained to use linear models than are trained to use GLMs; hence any analysis that can be frame as "linear model + something simple" will have be of use to more people. I'll leave it to someone else to point out the difference in the assumptions on the error distributions between a GLM and a seemingly similar transformation.

Transformation of the response impacts: (1) the shape of the relationship between E(Y|X=x) and x (albeit x might be a vector), (2) the conditional variance, (3) the conditional distribution of the response. When attempting to match  the usual assumptions of linear regression inferential procedures, it's rare for these transformations to all be the same. Indeed if you take a GLM they're (almost) guaranteed to be different. e.g. for canonical-link Poisson, log & square root for the first two and generally 2/3 power is better for improving the normal approximation of the conditional distribution.
